# Selenium printing text from the <h2> element of a web page

Tags: html, python-3.x, selenium-webdriver

This is a work-in-progress project where I enter a postcode (which will eventually become a list) into a website and then save the results from the website to a CSV using some kind of loop to move onto the next.

I'm having issues extracting the results from  below

[image]

```
**Great news! You can connect to the CityFibre network**
```

Below is the code I've created so far, and I would love any pointers or improvements.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import time

driver = webdriver.Firefox()

driver.get('https://cityfibre.com/')
assert 'CityFibre' in driver.title

time.sleep(2.5)

cookies = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "onetrust-accept-btn-handler")))
cookies.click()


PostCode = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,("//input[@class='w-full border rounded-lg border-grey-950 bg-white text-grey-950 ac-outline focus:border-cf-blue placeholder-grey-500 md:text-base lg:rounded-xl lg:rounded-tl-none lg:rounded-tl-none rounded-tl-none pr-32 pl-11 py-5']"));
PostCode.click()
PostCode.send_keys('EH17 7RY')
PostCode.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
time.sleep(2.5)
PostCode.send_keys(Keys.TAB)
PostCode.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)

time.sleep(15)

message = driver.find_element(By.TAG_NAME,('h2')[0]).text
print(message) 
print('The End')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a typo in your code.

You are getting first element from selector `h2` that is actually illegal action.

```
message = driver.find_element(By.TAG_NAME,('h2')[0]).text
```

I think, you meant

```
message = driver.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, 'h2')[0].text
```

Also, I suggest you to make locator more concrete and unique:

```py
message = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, '#js-availability-status-header h2').text
```

Comment: Thank you for the By.CSS_SELECTOR as it worked a treat.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the refined code that also uses WebDriverWait

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
import time

driver = webdriver.Firefox()

driver.get('https://cityfibre.com/')
assert 'CityFibre' in driver.title

cookies = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "onetrust-accept-btn-handler")))
cookies.click()

PostCode = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,("//input[@class='w-full border rounded-lg border-grey-950 bg-white text-grey-950 ac-outline focus:border-cf-blue placeholder-grey-500 md:text-base lg:rounded-xl lg:rounded-tl-none lg:rounded-tl-none rounded-tl-none pr-32 pl-11 py-5']"));
PostCode.click()
#PostCode.send_keys('EH17 7RY')     #multi house
PostCode.send_keys('AB15 8AB')      #single house
PostCode.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)


House = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH,("//div[contains(@class, 'absolute inset-0 overflow-x-hidden overflow-y-scroll')]"))))
House = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,("//input[@class='w-full border rounded-lg border-grey-950 bg-white text-grey-950 ac-outline focus:border-cf-blue placeholder-grey-500 md:text-base lg:rounded-xl lg:rounded-tl-none lg:rounded-tl-none rounded-tl-none pr-32 pl-11 py-5']"));
House.click()
House.send_keys(Keys.TAB)
House.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)

time.sleep(10)

#message = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,("//h2[contains(text(),'*')]")).text

message = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, '#js-availability-status-header h2').text
print(message) 
print('The End')

"""
#driver.quit()
"""
```